# The number of quadrilaterals formed from collinear and non-collinear points.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> There are $25$ points on a plane of which $7$ are collinear .
>   How many quadrilaterals can be formed from these points ?

I did this $^{25}C_{4}-^{7}C_{4}=12615$ quadrilaterals.

But the book is giving answer $^{25}C_{4}-^{7}C_{4}-^{7}C_{3}\times ^{18}C_{1}=11985$ quadrilaterals..

I don't know what is the correct idea .

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Answer (score 6):

Your idea is very close to correct.  A quadrilateral is formed by $4$ points, where at most $2$ may be colinear.  Thus, we have $$ \underbrace{^{25} C_4}_{\text{ choose four points}}  - \underbrace{^{7} C_4}_{\text{ subtract out  ways to pick four colinear points}} - \underbrace{^{7} C_3 \cdot ^{18} C_1 }_{\text{ subtract out ways to pick three colinear points}}$$

Comment: Why you also didn't subtract the number of ways to choose $2$ collinear points ?

Comment: Having $2$ co-linear points is totally okay (think of any side of a rectangle); in fact, any two points in the plane are co-linear.

Comment: Why there is a multiplication of $^{18}C_1$ at the last?

Comment: @Ganit because you have to pick 3 collinear points (that's the 7 choose 3 bit) and 1 not collinear with them (that's the 18 choose 1 bit)

Comment: @MarcusM : Got it...thanks!